# conda update spyder downgrades

Tags: python, updates, spyder, downgrade

I have currently version 3.1.2.
If I try:

conda update spyder

I get the following message:

spyder: 3.1.2     ----> 2.3.9

So, spyder will be downgraded.

I also have trouble with the variable explorer. No variables are shown.
Could these 2 problems be related?

Thx!
Liv

Comment: Please run `conda install qt pyqt` then try `conda update spyder` to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Done that. Gives the same issue. I also reinstalled anaconda but no improvement

Comment: Please post the full output that conda gives when you run `conda update spyder`